# Accessing data-xxx attribute values with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr-accessor

In Chrome console I can access(select) a required element and see the content as bellow:

```
> x = $(".sidebar-message a[data-id ='" + 2885 + "']")[0]

<a href=​"#" data-id=​"2885" data-uid=​"197025959" data-mobile=​"08021111134" data-lastname=​"Aliu" data-firstname=​"Isa" data-verified=​"true" data-assigned=​"false">​…​</a>​
```

Please how do i access the data-mobile , data-lastname etc using jQuery?

I tried `x.data-mobile` and `x[data-mobile]`, both are *`undefined`*

Comment: .attr('data-mobile') should work

Comment: @TommySchmidt on x? or directly on the $ object???

Comment: [`.data('mobile')`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: on an element (in your case the <a> tag).

Comment: @Juhana no luck `$(".sidebar-message a[data-id ='" + 2885 + "']")[0].data('mobile')`

Comment: Get rid of the `[0]`. If you want the first element only, use `.first()` or `:first`. Your string concatenation is also redundant. Try this: `$(".sidebar-message a[data-id ='2885']").first().data('mobile')`

Comment: `$(".sidebar-message a[data-id ='" + 2885 + "']").data('mobile')` Thanks!!!

Comment: heck with the down votes ... i'm just trying to learn. @Juhana thanks.

Comment: Downvotes are a little harsh, but this is a pretty standard 'RTFM' question. All you answers are solved with http://api.jquery.com

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I use SO as a quick learning resource, sometime, you are lucky to get  direct explanation, sometimes,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I done this by following code :

```
<a href="#" data-id="2885" data-uid="197025959" data-mobile="08021111134" data-lastname="Aliu" data-firstname="Isa" data-verified="true" data-assigned="false">Check Attribute Value</a>
<span id="MobileValue"></span>

<script>
$("a").click(function(){
var mobileValue=$(this).attr("data-mobile");
$("#MobileValue").html(mobileValue);

});
</script>
```

[Click Here](https://jsfiddle.net/adminsunil/qbexts1k/) for demo

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually in Html 5 you can access data attributes values also like this
$(".sidebar-message a"). data("id")